# how update a textview

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

simple program: 2 buttons (previous/next) and a textview to show text.

by intent I created an Index (inside a method)

```
private void index(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Index.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}
```

Index.class (with 3 buttons):

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        String result = "1";
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
        finish();
    }
});
```

Main.class

```
String value = "1";
final String prog1[] = new String[16];
final String prog2[] = new String[105];
final String prog3[] = new String[66];

int a;
int b;
int c=3;

int array1start = 0; int array1end = 15;
int array2start = 0; int array2end = 105;
int array3start = 0; int array3end = 65;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


if (value.equals("1")){

        a = array1start;
        b = array1end;
        prog=prog1; 

    }
    else if (value.equals("2")){
        a = array2start;
        b = array2end;
        prog=prog2; 

textView1.setText(""+prog[a]);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {

         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

          String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
          value=result;
          Toast toast2=Toast.makeText(this,"value: "+value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast2.show();
    }

    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         //Write your code on no result return 

    }}
    }//onAcrivityResult
```

at this point, choosen choice in index class should be change a result string to "value" string in main class

```
private void index(){


    Intent i = new Intent(this, Index.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);



}
```

my textview take data from array1 or array2 by index class

so, I dont' understand how update textview (because index value is correct).

thanks for the help

Comment: i don't understand your problem. value = result ?

Comment: result is a variable from Index.class (user choose by button1 or button2). If user click button1 then result="1", in the main class if result=1 then a = array1start; b = array1end; prog=prog1; but textview doesn't change.

Comment: Where is your onActivityResult() method. Couldn't find it

Comment: oncreate is not called again after onactivityresult. you need to put your setText in onActivityresult

Comment: thanks. But in the main class, when I press a button it update textview keeping new value? (value=result) I need update pointer of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put you code into function `onActivityResult`

```
if (value.equals("1")){

        a = array1start;
        b = array1end;
        prog=prog1; 

    }
    else if (value.equals("2")){
        a = array2start;
        b = array2end;
        prog=prog2; 

textView1.setText(""+prog[a]);
```